# Bootstrap Metro UI CSS Tab Control Component with AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, metro-ui-css

Using AngularJS I have this working code for tabs:

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="item in items">
        <tab-heading>TAB {{ $index+1 }}</tab-heading>
            <form>
            ...
            </form>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

and I'm trying to implement Metro UI CSS theme with its Tab Control component - http://metroui.org.ua/tab-control.html. I would like to combine the two things together.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tabs-on-top documentation at the url from above (https://metroui.org.ua/tabcontrol.html), you can get the Metro UI CSS theme Tab Control working with something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="tabcontrol">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <a ng-click="showPanel(item.panel)" style="cursor:pointer">{{item.title}} - TAB {{ $index+1 }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="frames">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="frame" ng-show="(activePanel == item.panel)">
            <div>{{item.title}}</div>
            <div>{{item.val}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular controller:

```
$scope.items = [
   { title: 'Home', val: 'Value1', panel: 'Panel1' },
   { title: 'Projects', val: 'Value2', panel: 'Panel2' },
   { title: 'Docs', val: 'Value3', panel: 'Panel3' },
   { title: 'Support', val: 'Value4', panel: 'Panel4' },
   { title: 'Contact', val: 'Value5', panel: 'Panel5' }
];

$scope.showPanel = function(panel) {
   $scope.activePanel = panel;
}
```

If each item has some ID (in this case, a panel ID), you can create a scope variable like `$scope.activePanel` to be set on an `ng-click` with `showPanel(item.panel)`. Then each tab's frame/div can have it's visibility set with `ng-show="(activePanel == item.panel)` to display the correct tab when clicked.

Hope that helps. Best of luck!